# How to deal with buffer garbage in ANSI C?

Tags: c

The fragment of code below doesn't work properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    int num;
    char str[40];
    scanf("%d",&num);
    gets(str);

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the scanf of an integer is impacting on the reading of the string with gets. I think that we could deal with this by using the fflush (stdin), but this is not in the ANSI C standard.

I would like to know if there is some standard way to deal with this in ANSI C.

Comment: Don't use `gets`. At all. Use `fgets` instead. And your program has no output, so it can't "not work properly".

Comment: Flushing an *input* stream has no defined effect.  Also, never use `gets()`.  It is unsafe, and has been removed from the language (though it may still be avilable to you as an extension).

Comment: probably your problem concerns the newline you enter after the num ...